# Is submitting a document falsely claiming that an inventor is not reachable illegal?

Tags: ownership, employee, perjury

An associate of mine and I jointly filed a patent, through my current employer. I was required to sign an assignment agreement when I started as a condition of employment.  My friend worked for the same employer at the time of the filing but has since left the company. My associate never signed an assignment agreement as a condition of employment.  My company recently sent my associate a document that, if signed, assigned patent ownership to my company, with no offer for compensation. My associate contends that the company never made an assignment agreement a requirement for his employment and therefore he is a co-owner of the IP in question. When my associate refused to assign ownership, my company submitted a document to the patent office that falsely claimed that my associate was not reachable. The patent attorney used by my company, our HR department and I have routinely exchanged correspondence with my associate. I believe that my company may have committed perjury in an attempt to effectively steal valuable IP that may be jointly owned by both my company and my associate. Am I correct and if I am, what advice do you have for my associate?

Answer (score 1):

A certified letter to both the company and their patent attorney/agents explaining these circumstances should put them on notice that your colleague is indeed reachable and intends to exert his interest in the particular invention. Lawyers have a duty to report matters of fact to the USPTO that affect the case and if they have filed that he is unreachable and know otherwise ... that is misconduct.

Find the attorney/agent of record using Public PAIR:
http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair

prove you are human using CAPTCHA to login then find the case:

Using the application number, control number, patent number, PTC number, publication number or international design registration number.